# Trying to traverse the HTML DOM structure using PHP?

Tags: php, dom

```
$p = new DOMDocument();
echo $data;
$static = $p->loadHTML($data);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("html")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("body")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("table")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("tr")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("td")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("table")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("tr")->item(5);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("td")->item(1);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("div")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("table")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("tr")->item(0);
$static = $static->getElementByTagName("td")->item(0);
$static = $static->etElementByTagName("center")->item(0);
echo $static;
```

Thats my code above, im not sure if I am doing it correctly but it seems like its right (Im trying to basically go through the structure to find the exact part I need). However I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementByTagName() on a non-object in blah on line 18

(Line 18 being the first "getElementByTagName")

I also get these errors if its anything to do with it:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
>   [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and
>   ending tag mismatch: td and center in
>   Entity, line: 83 in
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
>   [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and
>   ending tag mismatch: td and center in
>   Entity, line: 83 in
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
>   [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and
>   ending tag mismatch: td and center in
>   Entity, line: 87 in
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
>   [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end
>   tag : div in Entity, line: 91 in
>   on line 17

but yeah, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistyped the function name as `getElementByTagName`. The correct function name is `getElementsByTagName`. When I repeated your code with this correction it worked properly.

Answer (score 5):

First, fix your HTML so it's valid per those errors. Then do DOM processing.

You can also use DOMXpath and do

```
->evaluate('/body/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/div/table/tr/td/center')
```

Or you can just do `->evaluate('//center')` and grab all `center` elements.

*after* you get your HTML valid. You can also give that `center` element an id. Ideally, you should **never** use the center element though.

Comment: Ah Im getting data from a site, so its nothing I personally can change. I got rid of the html errors though but its still doing it. However that doesnt matter now since that looks like it will work for exactly what I need. Thanks for the fast response :)

Comment: Okay now it seems Im getting the same error, just with evaluate oddly Call to a member function evaluate() on a non-object in

Answer (score 3):

For the record:

Sometimes we can't fix malformed documents.
We can block those  warnings with the `@` (error control) operator.

```
$static = @$p->loadHTML($data);
```